# Setup Folder does not get populated when using magento-deploy-ignore in Composer

Tags: magento2, deploy, composer-install

Does anyone know why a composer setup like this could cause the post-cmd-install magento 2 base deploy to not fire correctly?

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "magento-deploy-ignore": {
        "*": [
            "/setup/config/application.config.php",
            "/.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md",
            "/pub/.user.ini",
            "/.user.ini",
            "/.gitignore"
        ]
    }
},
```

All other folders populate like pub and gihub, but not the setup folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always thought this `magento-deploy-ignore` was a per file but its actually per `map` definition in the modules composer json.

The code in the [magento composer installer](https://github.com/magento/magento-composer-installer/blob/abd3eb5cbcd63f38abbebca4abb82031d1eb09b5/src/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/Deploystrategy/DeploystrategyAbstract.php#L231-L245) that creates the files looks like this

```php
    /**
     * Normalize mapping parameters using a glob wildcard.
     *
     * Delegate the creation of the module's files in the given destination.
     *
     * @param string $source
     * @param string $dest
     * @throws \ErrorException
     * @return bool
     */
    public function create($source, $dest)
    {
        if($this->isDestinationIgnored($dest)){
            return;
        }
```

So if you have a look in map within `vendor/magento/magento2-base/composer.json` you can see how it has mostly each file spelled out like so

```json
            [
                "app/etc/db_schema.xml",
                "app/etc/db_schema.xml"
            ],
            [
                "app/etc/di.xml",
                "app/etc/di.xml"
            ],
            [
                "app/etc/registration_globlist.php",
                "app/etc/registration_globlist.php"
            ],
```

Unfortunately Magento was not so specific with the `setup` directory and only define its `map` like

```json
            [
                "setup",
                "setup"
            ],
```

That means the [isDestinationIgnored](https://github.com/magento/magento-composer-installer/blob/abd3eb5cbcd63f38abbebca4abb82031d1eb09b5/src/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/Deploystrategy/DeploystrategyAbstract.php#L200-L216) function to decide whether to copy over the files has dodgy inputs

```php
    /**
     * @param string $destination
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected  function isDestinationIgnored($destination)
    {
        $destination = '/'.$destination;
        $destination = str_replace('/./','/', $destination);
        $destination = str_replace('//','/', $destination);
        foreach($this->ignoredMappings as $ignored){
            if( 0 === strpos($ignored,$destination) ){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I hacked it locally to add this echo

```
        if( 0 === strpos($ignored,$destination) ){
            echo "$destination is ignored by $ignored" . PHP_EOL;
            return true;
        }
```

Then I did `rm -rf vendor/magento/magento2-base` and then ran `composer install` and I can see stuff like

```
/.gitignore is ignored by /.gitignore
/.user.ini is ignored by /.user.ini
/setup is ignored by /setup/config/modules.config.php
```

So there we are. Because the string check within `isDestinationIgnored` matches it doesn't copy over the whole setup directory.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento-composer-installer/pull/34